# jquery mobile listview is not displaying for the dynamic content for second time

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, dynamic-content, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a ul-li list(say parent list), on clicking of each li from the parent i am creating one more ul-li list(say child list) dynamically. problem is, JQM's listview template for child list is loading for first click from the parent list. but it is not loading if i click the same li or some other li from parent, instead it is loading the normal html ul-li list not a JQM's list.

**Sample code,**

HTML:

```html
<ul id="parentUlContainer" data-role="listview">
<li id="one">first<li>
<li id="two">second<li>
</ul>
```

Script:

```js
$("#parentUlContainer li").click(function(){
 //creating dynamic child ul-li list with respect to the #one or #two of parent.
});
```

I don't know how to use and where to use the listview's refresh method. kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the list view needs to be refreshed in your js after you add the new list item

```
$( "#parentUlContainer" ).listview( "refresh" );
```

I have created a JSfiddle with example usage:
http://jsfiddle.net/ajpalma/n9dSG/

I also noticed the closing list items were missing the leading "/" and fixed this in my fiddle.